# Is there another way pushing data to array in js

Tags: javascript, arrays

here is my code pushing data to an array variable, but I am getting a blank array. what am I doing wrong?

```
let users = []

//looping ajax response here
for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++ ) {
  users.push(response[i].user_name)
}
```

when I run console.log this is what I got

```
console.log(users) // Array[]
```

Comment: what is `response.length` before the loop .... though, considering the comment "looping ajax response here", your issue is probably with how you're (not) dealing with asynchronous responses

Comment: @JaromandaX `console.log(response.length) // Array(31)`

Comment: you are claiming that `console.log(response.length)` outputs `Array(31)`? hint: no, it doesn't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `map` function also of Javascript Array like below but before that you need to make sure that response has data in array type.

First we are checking response is not undefined and after that we are looping from response if response has data.

```
//looping ajax response here
let users = response && response.map(x => {
  return x.user_name;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are missing the `i` variable value in response.

```
var response=[{user_name:'abc'},{user_name:'def'}]

let users = [];

for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++ ) {
users.push(response[i].user_name)
}
```

After using this code you should get the result in users array.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can easily add a new value to the existing array without using the push() method
just use the ES6+ feature for array destructuring.

here is the code! very easy simple and need

```js
var numberArray = [];
for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
    numberArray = [...numberArray, index * 10]; // destructring the old array and adding new element
}
console.log(numberArray); // update array
```